# Flask response backslash issue

Tags: python-3.x, flask

#app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # return jsonify({"error":})
    return "characters are \/ ,-_''?@:;&"


#output characters are \/ ,-_''?@:;&



@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # return jsonify({"error":})
    return {"error":"characters are \/ ,-_''?@"":;&"}

#output {"error":"characters are \\/ ,-_''?@:;&"}


I need an output like 
{"error":"characters are \/ ,-_''?@:;&"}
```

I have searched a lot , but i couldnt understand this.
why my above code is not working and how do i fix this ?
I am newbie,Please help me out in this .

Comment: use escape sequence to escape backslash . `characters are \\/ ,-_''?@:;&" `

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r Yes i tried, but i got results like characters are \\/ ,-_''?@:;&",

Comment: Well if nothing works I'd recommend changing the server's return data from the front end... Just replace the first \ with nothing

Comment: @Patch are you meant do string replace in frontend ?

Comment: Maybe get the request with ajax when you receive the data(what you return here) you can do what I said in the comment, and then put the contents wherever you like (.innerHTML or .text() for jQuery). Maybe you can also change it whenever the data changes in a specific element

Comment: @Patch okay. it will helps somewhat. But why can't we fix this issue in server(flask or python) itself?

Comment: @Ananth.P that is kind of weird.... The double backslash should've worked

Comment: @Patch Have you tried to run my code ?

Comment: @Ananth.P No but I saw a question about it ( specifically about dicts... I it's because of Flask

Comment: @Patch please help me out in this issue ?

Comment: @Ananth.P I did I literally told you what to do